# Prevent direct traffic to URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to prevent direct access to a URL (http://www.example.com/gated-asset). Is there any way to add code to the htaccess file that would redirect all direct traffic to another page (http://www.example.com/form)?

I have tried the following code in my htaccess file, but all pages, including the home page, redirect to www.example.com/form.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://go.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/form [R,L]
```

The entire .htaccess file looks like this (it is a WordPress site):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://go.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/form [R,L]
```

I have also tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://go.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /form/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ /gated-asset/ [R,L]
```

As well as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://go.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/gated-asset http://www.example.com/form/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `http://` in the referrer check if you are matching the beginning (`^`). Unlike `HTTP_HOST`, `HTTP_REFERER` requires it. In addition, the referring URL may include a `REQUEST_URI`, and so closing the expression at the domain will prevent it from working.

```bsh
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://go.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/form [R,L]
```

If you don't want to include the `http://`, then you can use the following condition instead:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !go.example.com [NC]
```

However, I would recommend the first example be used.

Also included here are the `R` and `L` flags. `R` is implied if the rewrite is to an external resource, but it is generally better to include it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately, the home page is still being redirected.  I only need a particular page redirected.  Can you offer a solution to that?

Comment: You may have another directive, either in your `.htaccess` file or in your app/script, that is redirecting to the home page. You should probably make use of a debugging tool to see what may be causing the redirect. The *Network* tab of the Chrome console is a good place to start.